# Find 3rd point in 3D space based on position of 2 points

Tags: 3d

Assuming i have 2 points $P_1$ and $P_2$ having coordinates of

$P_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$

$P_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$

I want to find the coordinates of a 3rd point ($P_3$) where it creates a straight line if connected with $P_1$ and $P_2$

P3 should be after $P_2$ on the virtually-created-line (aka --$P_1$--$P_2$--$P_3$--) and should have distance $D$ from $P_2$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The solution is
$$
\vec{P_2}+D\frac{\vec{P_1P_2}}{|\vec{P_1P_2}|}
$$
You take the vector $P_2$, and you add $D$ times the unit (length one) vector that points from $P_1$ towards $P_2$.

Answer (score 3):

1. find a vector that points toward $P_2$ from $P_1$.  That's
   $$\vec v = P_2 - P_1 = (x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1, z_2-z_1)$$
2. find a vector *of length 1* in that same direction.  This can be done by finding the length
   $$|\vec v|=\sqrt{x_v^2+y_v^2+z_v^2}$$
   and dividing the components of $v$ by it:
   $$\vec v^* = \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}=\left(\frac{x_v}{|\vec v|},\frac{y_v}{|\vec v|},\frac{z_v}{|\vec v|}\right)$$
3. find a vector of length $D$ in that same direction.
   $$d=D\vec v^*=(Dx_v^*,Dy_v^*,Dx_v^*)$$
4. $P_3$ is now $d$ away from $P_2$.
   $$P_3=P_2+d=(x_2+x_d,y_2+y_d,z_2+z_d)$$